# How to pass parameters to my query but not execute it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass date parameters to my query which is stored in my config table and insert that updated query to another column. I have a queryname column also by which I identify my queries which are oracle queries and are huge in length. So that's why I don't want them to be executed but only to pass parameters to them and then store the updated query to another column in SQL Server. Also I will execute this stored procedure in ssis and will give the queryname at runtime

So as of now my code is:-

```
Create spUpdateQuery
    @queryname varchar(500)
As 
Begin
    Declare @date1 int
    Declare @date2 int
    Declare @oraclequery nvarchar(max)

    Select @date1 = firstdate, @date2 = lastdate, @oraclequery = query 
    from config_table 
    where queryname = @queryname 

    Set @updatedquery = (@oraclequery, @date1, @date2)
End
```

How do I do it?

I am getting dates value from my config table as well. 
Please help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would leave them separate and then pass the parameters at runtime.

But, if you want to, you can treat @updatedquery and @oraclequery just like any other nvarchar.

```
SELECT @updatedquery = REPLACE(@oraclequery, '@date1', @date1)
SELECT @updatedquery = REPLACE(@oraclequery, '@date2', @date2)
```

Make sure you have quotation marks where you need them in @oraclequery, and you might want to wrap the @date1 and @date1 in a CONVERT to control the format you get in your final string.